# submit button does not work after using display inline

Tags: css

I don't know what else to do. I am a newbie and doing what I thought was 
    simple coding. I have tried everything including display:inline and 
    display:inline important;". I am trying to put the submit button on the 
    same line with the same style attributes (blue, white words, etc.). 
    Please help!

```html
<form action="/action_page.php">
    <input type="textarea" name="firstname" placeholder="Enter your address 
    to determine if we buy in your neighborhood" style=
    "border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    border-top: 1px solid #d6d4d4;
    border-right: 1px solid #d6d4d4;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d6d4d4;
    border-left: 1px solid #d6d4d4;
    height: 52px;
    width: 618px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    color: #161616;
    line-height: 1.1;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: open sans;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-align: left;
    text-align-last: left;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,.5);">
    <input type="submit" value="Get Started" style="font-weight: 400; line- 
    height: 3.1;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #12208e;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    border-top: 0;
    border-right: 0;
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-left: 0;
    height: 50px;
    width: 160px;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-right: 14px;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    padding-left: 14px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 1;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: open sans;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align: center;
    text-align-last: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: #12208e;
    background-image: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;">
</form>
```

Comment: Since you are a begginer as you said, my first suggestion is: move that enormous amount of style to a CSS file and link the elements with the CSS classes using a `class` or `id`. This will make your code much more readable and easier to find bugs

Comment: Also, if you're going to use the same value to a property, example: `5px` to `border-radius` there's no need to set it to every corner separatedly, just use `border-radius: 5px` and all corners (top-left, bottom-left, etc...) will have the same value.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few things that are causing errors with your code. First of all, to get your desired layout add in a div that wraps around the two input elements like so:

```
<div class="form-row">
    <input type="textarea" name="firstname" placeholder="Enter your address to determine if we buy in your neighborhood" class="name-input">
    <input type="submit" value="Get Started" class="btn-submit">
</div>
```

Apply these styles to that div to make the two input elements appear "on one-line":

```
.form-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

You also had a spelling mistake in the styles for your button, where you had `line- height: 3.1;`, however I removed that line as you were overriding it with another line-height rule further down.

```css
html {
  font-family: open sans;
}

.form-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.name-input {
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #d6d4d4;
  height: 52px;
  width: 618px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 5px;
  color: #161616;
  line-height: 1.1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: open sans;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

.btn-submit {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #12208e;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 160px;
  padding: 0 14px;
  margin: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
}
```

```html
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <div class="form-row">
    <input type="textarea" name="firstname" placeholder="Enter your address to determine if we buy in your neighborhood" class="name-input">
    <input type="submit" value="Get Started" class="btn-submit">
  </div>
</form>
```

***Note***: Since you are setting a fixed width on those two elements, they won't fit on one line on very small screens, or if other elements are added to it.

I greatly recommend splitting your CSS into a separate CSS file like in this snippet. It will allow you to better see what is going on. Also if you use a decent IDE (code editor) it will pick up these errors for you as well.

Here are some resources you can use to learn more about [CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_intro.asp) and [HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp). Good luck!